# Correct superscript spacing for new mathbin

Tags: spacing, macros, symbols, superscripts, unicode-math

I redefined the `\div` command so that it's U+2215 aka ∕, but for some reason when I use it as a superscript the spacing between this symbol and its numbers is really tight (works fine in displaymode or otherwise). Below is what I created:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}    
% I personally use MinionMath-Regular.otf but XITS Math 
% also shows this property, to a lesser degree
\newcommand{\olddiv}{\mathbin{÷}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*\div{\ensuremath{\mathbin{∕}}}}

\begin{document}
$a^{1\div2}$ $1\div2$ 
\end{document}
```

This is the outcome (with XITS Math):

[image]

It may not seem *that* horrible, but taking a look at what happens with MinionMath-Regular you can see why I'm concerned:

[image]

Theoretically I could just put in spaces, as in `1/ \div/ 2`, but that doesn't look great and I think there should be an easier, more permanent way to accomplish good spacing. I'd appreciate any advice with this!

Comment: `\mathbin` does not add spaces in scriptsyle and it seems / has no sidebearings at all in that font, so if tex doesn't add space it touches teh adjacent characters....

Comment: you could use `\renewcommand*\div{\mathbin{\mskip1mu∕\mskip1mu}}` or whatever looks good. (You don't want `\ensuremath` really: math commands should be just math).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the `\mskip1mu` also affects the displaystyle / regular mode spacing of `\div`, but I want that spacing to remain the same; it's only when it's in superscript that I have a problem. I would ideally like the same spacing (proportionally) for superscript as inline / displaystyle / etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\renewcommand*\div{\mathbin{\mskip1mu\nonscript\mskip-1mu%
                            ∕%
                            \mskip1mu\nonscript\mskip-1mu}}
```

or some value other than `1mu` the skip is always added but in non-script (ie text and display) styles add the negative amount to cancel it out.

Comment: This is a really clever answer, thank you! :)