# Spacing around math operator in sub-/superscript

Tags: spacing, math-operators

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

What I have:
\[x^{1+1}\]

What I would like:
\[x^{1\,+\,1}\]

That is, I will like to have spacing around the operator as in `$1+1$'.\\[\baselineskip]
\textsf{Question:} How do I get the above throughout my document without having to add \verb|\,| on each side of the operator every time?

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214147/correct-superscript-spacing-for-new-mathbin/214159#214159  you can define a macro \myplus that adds the space and removes it again:-) then if you are feeling brave you could define `+` to access that macro.

Comment: the spacing you see is built into the design of tex.  the spacing used in math is laid out in a table in the *texbook* on p.170.  essentially the same table is in *tex by topic* (`texdoc texbytopic`) on p.205.  it's not easy to change globally.  the suggestion by david is probably your best "way out".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the pointer. (If you create an answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the comment, Barbara!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg an answer with a pointer or do you actually want an answer:-) oh by the way I think the table barabara mentions _is_ changeable from luatex if I remember so if luatex is an option there are different answers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An actual answer will be nice. `:-)` Lua(La)TeX is not an option for the document(s) I'm writing at the moment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Am I right in saying that before and after `+` and `-` in sub-/superscript, a medium space (= 4mu) is inserted on each side?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg -- nope.  `+` and `-` are "bin", and digits are "ord".  the notation in the table is "(2)" for either order.  while "2" = medium space, the fact that the value is enclosed in parentheses indicates that the space is inserted "only in text and display mode, not in script or scriptscript mode".  in most situations laid out in the table, parentheses are the order of the day, so ... not in scripts.  when in doubt, assume "tight spacing" in scripts.  (the relevant note is on p.205 in *tex by topic*.)

Comment: Altough not for @SvendTveskæg, a general LuaTeX answer would be welcome.

Comment: I think that this trick is by @barbarabeeton: `x^{\text{$1+1$}}`. But, no, you *don't* want it.

Comment: @Manuel done, see answer

Comment: Updated answer, but I don't think it's usable really apart from the luatex version, sorry:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Luatex has primitives to control the space added between each class in each math style, so to control the space between a mathord and a mathbin in script style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$a+b x^{a+b}$

\Umathordbinspacing\scriptstyle=10mu
\Umathbinordspacing\scriptstyle=10mu

$a+b x^{a+b}$

\end{document}
```

---

For classic TeX engines You can do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\realplus}{\mathbin}{operators}{"2B}
\begin{document}
$a+b x^{a+b} +cx^{+c}$

%\Umathordbinspacing\scriptstyle=10mu
%\Umathbinordspacing\scriptstyle=10mu


\def\z{{\mskip\medmuskip{\realplus}\mskip\medmuskip}}

$a\z b x^{a \z b} \z  cx^{\z c}$

\catcode`\+\active\let+\z
\catcode`\+12
\mathcode`\+="8000

$a+b x^{a+b} +cx^{+c}$

\end{document}
```

But it's not so good, it always adds the space so only works if `+` is used as a binary operator between to mathord atoms. Note the final prefix `+c` in the last term gets the wide space, which isn't really what you want, you'd need a separate command to access a prefix `+`.

In an answer linked via comments I suggested a construct using `\nonscript` which looks more involved but actually I think it has the same flaw.

The version suggested by egreg using `\text` gets the correct spacing but it requires more markup than just adding the space (although of course you could define your own variant `\sp` command that made superscripts using this construct).

Comment: Please see updated question, David.

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't want it. The rules for mathematical spaces have been studied by Knuth by examining several documents with mathematical contents produced during a wide amount of time.

Perhaps some national typographic tradition spaces operation and relation symbols also in superscripts and subscripts. This doesn't mean it's good: tight spacing there *is* good, in general. Some occasional mishap can be fixed by hand: if you want a beautiful document, you have to work on it. Michelangelo didn't just use hammer and chisel to make his famous [Pietà](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AMichelangelo's_Pieta_5450.jpg).

This is an image from a book by Karl Weierstraß, “Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen: Erstes Heft”, 1856 ([see on Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=EuJUAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:Weierstrass&hl=it&sa=X&ei=HOSZVKOzHsPXas31gJAO&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false))

[image]

You can see that sums in superscripts are tightly set, which is not the case for sums in normal type.

---

Here's a trick that I remember used by barbara beeton:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\catcode`^=12
\catcode`_=12

\begingroup\lccode`~=`^\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\SPACED\sp}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\SPACED\sb}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`^="8000 \mathcode`_="8000 }

\makeatletter
\def\SPACED#1#2{#1{\text{$\m@th#2$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle x^{1+1}+\sum_{1\le k\le n}k^2$

The original: {\catcode`^=7 \catcode`_=8
  $\displaystyle x^{1+1}+\sum_{1\le k\le n}k^2$}
\end{document}
```

The `\displaystyle` is just by way of example.

[image]

I have no doubt about what version I'd choose.

Comment: Thanks, egreg. Are you sure Michelangelo didn't just mock something up? `:)`

Comment: did i *really* do that???  (if so, i should be scolded severely!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton did you really set the book by  Weierstraß? Probably:-)

Comment: Aaah, so `leqno` is the reason for that weird single brace habit!! Finally I know.

Comment: @percusse Actually the system is centered and (3.) is not at the left margin but at two quads from the brace.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- you know, obviously, that i'm old enough to be your mother, but really, weierstraß died before *my* mother was born.  hmmmmph.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Happy Christmas!