# How can I change the kerning of all relations in script styles?

Tags: subscripts, kerning, relation-symbols

Let's say that I am dissatisfied with the lack of horizontal spacing around relations in scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle. I would like to \mkern them by 1mu on either side, because I think that looks better.

If I was just going to do this once, I would probably do it like this.

```
\sum_{g \mkern1mu \in \mkern1mu G}
```

If I knew I was going to do this several times, it would probably be smarter to do put it in a macro instead.

```
\def\mykern#1{\mkern1mu#1\mkern1mu}
\sum_{g \mykern\in G}
```

But let's say I want to go nuclear, and make TeX do this all throughout the document, to all \mathrel's in subscripts, without having to type out a macro each time. Is that possible to accomplish, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: [Spacing around math operator in sub-/superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219278/82917) is not an exact duplicate (**Bin** instead of **Rel**) but the concept is the same.