# Reinstate display-style spacing without changing font size

Tags: spacing, displaystyle

To improve legibility, I'd sometimes like to reinstate display-style spacing in sub- or superscripts. However, adding `\displaystyle` also changes the font size and switches `\tfrac` to `\frac`, as can be seen from the following example

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&e^{-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}\\
&e^{\displaystyle-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase spacing around operators like `+`, `-`, `\cdot` without affecting any other part of the output?

Comment: Normally, `\mathbin` spacing goes away in smaller (`\scriptstyle`)  math sizes that are found in sub/super-scripts.  You can manually add it back in the manner of `\,+\,`, etc., though I presume there is an automatic way to do this as well (though I don't know it).  However, egreg will tell you not to do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219278/spacing-around-math-operator-in-sub-superscript/219284#219284.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214147/correct-superscript-spacing-for-new-mathbin

Comment: `\displaystyle` is a bit excessive in a superscript, you could use `\textstyle` but it would still increase the font size

Answer (score 2):

You could locally make `-` and `+` mathop rather than mathbin then they would get thin (rather than medium) space, even in superscripts

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&e^{-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}\\
&e^{\textstyle -S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}\\
&e^{
\mathcode`\+="102B
\mathcode`\-="1200
 -S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Although that also loses the automatic loss of spacing for the prefix `-` unless you use `{-}S`

Comment: The third option looks nice. What would be the `\mathcode` to increase spacing for `\cdot`? Is there some place to look these up?

Comment: @Casimir `\mathchardef\cdot="1201`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `\exp` notation.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Equation \eqref{A} is unreadable
\item Equation \eqref{B} is confusing
\item Equation \eqref{C} is right
\item Equation \eqref{D} is better: the dot is almost never used
\item Equation \eqref{E} is possibly better
\end{itemize}
\begin{align}
\label{A}
&e^{-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi 
    - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}\\
\label{B}
&e^{\textstyle-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi
    - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k}\\
\label{C}
&\exp\Bigl(-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi 
           - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k\Bigr)\\
\label{D}
&\exp\Bigl(-S[\phi] + J\phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi R_k \phi - J \varphi_k 
           + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k R_k \varphi_k\Bigr)\\
\label{E}
&\exp\Bigl(-S[\phi] + J\phi - \tfrac{1}{2} \phi R_k \phi - J \varphi_k 
           + \tfrac{1}{2} \varphi_k R_k \varphi_k\Bigr)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to preserve the spacing around the operation symbols you can use `\text`, but I don't recommend doing it. Prefer `\exp`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
e^{\text{$-S[\phi] + J \cdot \phi - \frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot R_k \cdot \phi
    - J \cdot \varphi_k + \frac{1}{2} \varphi_k \cdot R_k \cdot \varphi_k$}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, `\cdot`indicates a particular scalar product. Leaving it out would create ambiguity. But I guess you're right, `\exp` is the way to go here.